# jQuery/JS: How to create a SEO-friendly link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an SEO-friendly link from the input in a text input box.  I do so on the blur event when the cursor leaves the input in question.  I can get the text in the input to appear in the desired input (for the link), but my link isn't hyphenated and special characters are not replaced with hyphens.  I am trying to do a global string replace, but the expression expects a string, not a variable.  At least from what I can tell.  Also, I can't figure out a better way to match the list of special characters, other than an array and a loop.  Can someone help?  My desire is to create link like this: http://domain.com/this-is-my-link.  Here is my code:

```
$('#title').blur(function() {   
      var hyphenated;   
      hyphenated = urlTitle($(this).val());             
      $('#link').val(hyphenated);       
});


function urlTitle(text) {       
    var characters = [' ', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '=', '_', '{', '}', '[', ']', '|', '/', '<', '>', ',', '.', '?', '--']; 

    for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
         var char = String(characters[i]);
         text = text.replace(/char/g, '-');

}           
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Are search engines even executing client-side code?

Comment: I am creating a tool so our dealers can use our CMS to create SEO-friendly links to their articles.  The link would not be executed client-side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your escaping function:

```
text = text.replace(/char/g, '-');
```

This literally matches "char". So if you give it `I'm building a string out of chars`, [it will return](http://jsfiddle.net/rTkLA/) `i'm building a string out of -s`.

If you want to make up a regex expression dynamically using a variable, you'll need to build it using a string and the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/User%3aPotappo/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp_%28constructor%29).

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp("\\" + char, "g"), '-');
```

Note that when using this format you do not need to specify the delimiting characters (the forward slashes before and after), and that the flags are passed as the second parameter to the constructor. I also prepended a backslash to escape any special characters you might want to replace.

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pNcVc/)

Comment: How would I remove any trailing hyphens?

Comment: @shummel7845 You could use [these trim functions](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-trim.html). [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/pNcVc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variable names like that in regex literals, (/char/). Either use a RegExp object with properly escaped values, or make a single regexp literal that matches all the characters you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

I have a version that works something like this:

```
function urlTitle(text) {
    var removeRe = /[^\w\s]/ig,
        spacesRe = /[\s]/ig;
    return text.toLowerCase().replace(removeChars, '').replace(spaceChars, '-');
}
```

This has a weakness that double spaces are turned into double '-'s. That could be improved upon with another regex.